# ¿Cómo decodificar un archivo en base64 a su archivo original?

Tags: base64, sequelize.js

Estoy subiendo archivos (imagenes) a mi base de datos en la cual tengo una entidad "imagen" que posee una columna "IMAGEN" del tipo BLOB mediante este código:

```
                const files = req.files;
                    let image = fs.readFileSync(files.path);
                    let encodeImage = image.toString('base64');

                    let finalImage = {
                        contentType: files.mimetype,
                        image: new Buffer(encodeImage, 'base64')
                    };

                    Image.create({
                        IMAGEN: finalImage,
                    }).then(imagen =>{
                        res.json(imagen);
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        next(err);
                    })
```

Y lo que obtengo en mi cliente cuando hago un GET es:

```
ACTIVO: 1
BORRADO: 0
FECHA_CREACION: "2019-07-10T15:13:58.000Z"
FECHA_MODIFICACION: null
IMAGEN:
    data: (15) [91, 111, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 32, 79, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 93]
    type: "Buffer"
IMAGEN_ID: 69
POST_ID: 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo hace poco estuve trabajando con imagenes decodificadas sobre base 64 que se insertan en un API y se devuelven del lado del cliente en su formato original.

Para esto use una herramienta diferente, se llama [filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Con esta herramienta solamente tienes que poner en el `src=""` propiedad el base64  tal cual ya sea que este en un json, un array o sea un objeto y el solo te lo decodifica y te devuelve la imagen.

```html
<div>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="punto rojo" />
</div>
```

Ademas puedes verificar con un decode online que el archivo este bien codificado 
o decodificado para finalmente ser usado.  =)

Comment: cual pagina usas para codifica y decodificar la imagen, podrias agregarla?

Comment: Utilizo esta pagina:   https://www.base64decode.org/                         
pero prefiero hacerlo manualmente para esto tome como ejemplo este codigo y lo modifique: https://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/CfilG         dentro de el uno puede tomar tomar el valor decoficado que corresponde a reader.result().